# Samsung Galaxy Tab: Cannot download from Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-tab, downloading

I bought this tablet without a SIM card. I have a WiFi connection, but it still doesn't let me download from the Android Market.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I just edited your question -- but still, some more information is needed: Which Android version have you running on the device (as you are speaking of "Android Market", which is "Google Play" for over a year now)? Have you created a Google account? How do you access it?

Answer (score 0):

By your reference, you are using android market, not Google play store. This then, suggest that you need to update the store, otherwise you are not downloading anything. The store has been as Google play store for a bit over a yes now, so anyone using android market are severely outdated. You ***may*** have to download the apk, and install it, force updating it.